# Error running cuda with opengl

Tags: nvidia, cuda, c++, programming

I am trying to compile julia example code using the command "nvcc -lglut julia.cu -o julia" and getting the following error

```
Starting build...

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/tmpxft_00004758_00000000-11_julia_gpu.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glFlush'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
```

I have also tried installing OpenGL but get the same error.

Comment: `DSO missing from command line` suggests you should be running nvcc with `-lGL` as well as `-lglut`